# Drag MKAnnotation from another view and drop to MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios4, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation

Is it possible to do that ? drag a MKAnnotation(pin) from another popup view (such as custom toolbox) to drop on MKMapView.

Answer (score 0):

MKAnnotations only live inside the MKMapView. You could create an animation that achieves the same effect.